# FQL facebook people lives here

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, country

i would like to know how can i get a list of ids of people which are living on some place, mentioned in page for this place, there is a button "People lives here" so is there any way to get that list as JSON or something?

Comment: I got for example this page: https://www.facebook.com/pages/Vsenory-St%C5%99edo%C4%8Desk%C3%BD-Kraj-Czech-Republic/110468948979744?fref=ts
And here is the button: http://prntscr.com/3s2b6r
Sorry for different language. The pictures should be the same.

Comment: Actually, that link says "People been here" I think. That's a big difference

Comment: Well in my language there is "Bydlí tady" which in english means "Lives here", so thank u for your help, i am going to investigate how to handle been_here because they're probably the same links, just badly translated :)

Comment: I'm quite sure they are the same. See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `checkin_count`, please refer to my answer here: [Facebook Graph API checkin list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24146745/facebook-graph-api-checkin-list/24157342#24157342)

Comment: Well thanks for this, what disappointed me is that i cant get the list, because directly on facebook u can see the list, and what can be seen on facebook, should be visible through facebook API, but thank so much :)

Comment: You're welcome! It's unfortunately not the case with FB that everything is available via the Graph API, but I guess it's the same for other big sites as well. Best regards from Germany to the beautiful Czech Republic :-)

Comment: Well it is sad, but i think i can get over it :D Best regards from CZ too, looking forward to visit Germany again :)